# Displaying a pagination widget in Go

Tags: go, web, go-html-template, go-http

I am using HTML templating in Go to render a pagination widget. I am trying to follow an example of how to do it from here: https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/adding-pagination-to-your-website.stml

This is my code so far:

```golang
// Item size like call 2 item from database
var pagesize = 2
var PaginationSize int = 6
var isActive string
Pagination := make([]int, PaginationSize)

for i := 0; i < PaginationSize; i++ {
    if RequestPageNumber <= page {
        Pagination[i] = i + 1
    } else {
        Pagination[i] = RequestPageNumber + i
    }

    if i == 0 {
        isActive = " active"
    } else {
        isActive = ""
    }
    Info.Pagination += template.HTML(
        fmt.Sprintf(`<li class="page-item%s"><a class="page-link" href=?id=%v>%v</a></li>`,
            isActive, RequestPageNumber+i, RequestPageNumber+i))
}
```

I would like to improve this by making the pagination list update only when the active page becomes a multiple of `PaginationSize`. For example, when the displayed pagination shows

```
(1), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

If the user clicks on 2, I would like to see

```
1, (2), 3, 4, 5, 6
```

But my current code displays

```
(2), 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

After the page has advanced past 6, the page list should look like

```
7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 ,13 ,14
```

The data wrapped in this pagination view may be in a database, so I'd also appreciate tips on how to make this work with a database, if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check next solution

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

const PSIZE = 5

func pager(pageNo int) {
    var start int = pageNo/(PSIZE-1)*(PSIZE-1) + 1
    if pageNo%(PSIZE-1) == 0 {
        start -= PSIZE - 1
    }

    for i := start; i < start+PSIZE; i++ {
        if i == pageNo {
            fmt.Printf("(%d) ", i)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", i)
        }
    }
    fmt.Print("\n")
}

func main() {
    pager(4)
    pager(8)
    pager(9)
}
```

Output

```
1 2 3 (4) 5 
5 6 7 (8) 9 
(9) 10 11 12 13
```

https://play.golang.org/p/rFslGe2OE0k